# CakePHP how to create a route for a pdf file

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3

I've a pdf document in my CAKEPHP webroot. I want to create a route to that pdf file with the name `/mydoc`. I'm using `CAKEPHP 1.3`

When we type `example.com/mydoc` it should open that pdf.

Any direct ways to write direct `route` and it will be achieved without using `controller` and `action`.

Comment: Is this a dynamically generated file or a static one?

Comment: Static one. As i've mentioned "I've a pdf document in my CAKEPHP webroot"

Comment: Its not the right way if you are going to try without a controller.if you are ready ro follow framework flow then >use this trick .Make a controller of any name and you can controll it from there...try thishttp://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/952/File-extensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a route, this will have to invoke a controller, in which you may output the PDF using a Cake Media View. That seems rather like overkill though. Instead, just add a URL rewrite rule to `app/webroot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^/mydoc$ files/the_file.pdf
```

(Untested, may need some fiddling.) This way the file download is handled by the webserver directly without having to go through Cake.

Answer (score 2):

As of CakePHP 2.9, you can put the following in your routes.php file.

```
Router::redirect('/mydoc', 'files/mydoc.pdf');
```

Comment: how to do this with `array('language'=>'en|fr');`